# Bar graphs have disappeared

Tags: civireport

Bar and pie charts no longer render - and I didn't do anything on my end. I just get a little box now where there used to be a chart.

I've cleared caches and just did an upgrade from 4.4.5 to 4.6.4 in the hopes it would be solved - no joy.

Resources and extension directories are set; I'm stumped here. Any ideas? Thanks!

Further info:

Update: After turning debugging on and off (and seeing no errors), bar graphs now work on the report pages, but not in the dashlets, unless viewing the dashlet fullscreen, in which case they now appear. This is for Firefox and Safari; in Chrome, the graphs don't appear under any circumstances, even when viewing the full report. Hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

Did you change browser?

I experience that Firefox fails to show graphs in CiviCRM, even though it displays without problems in Chrome or Safari

Answer (score 1):

Ad-blocking software in your browser can sometimes cause this, as can an outdated (or missing) copy of Flash.

Comment: Civi demo is fine in Firefox and Safari, so as far as those two browsers, that wouldn't be it. Graphs don't come up in Chrome, though, on the demo site, so as far as Chrome is concerned, I'll look into Flash - thanks!

Comment: Checking back in here - the graphs come up fine on the report setup page and when viewed fullscreen; they just don't display from the dashlets. There's just a small white box with a grey border - that's it. (I'd attach a screen capture if I could figure out how to do so here.) Thanks for any ideas!